# Comma consistency

Tags: commas

"If both parties agree on who should receive the **bond**, they can lodge a Bond Refund Form with the relevant organisation. If an agreement is unable to be **reached** the matter will be referred to a Court to determine an outcome". If a lease contains such a **clause** the following can apply...

Is the comma after the word 'bond' optional in this scenario? as I noticed that it is missing after the word 'reached' and the word "clause"

Comment: I'd personally have had one following "reached" as well.

Comment: The comma is not *required* in any of the three.  Having a comma or not does not significantly change the way the words will be interpreted, or cause the reader to "stumble".  I personally would consider a comma more idiomatic in the second than in the first (though I'd be tempted to put a comma in all three).

Comment: Having comma(s) or not having them, doesn't change the meaning, but they look reader-friendly.

Comment: It’s a matter of taste. I would never put a comma after an “if” clause, and certainly not inconsistently. But don’t post questions on punctuation. It’s a waste of time.

Comment: I agree that the cases are parallel and could have been treated alike. So I venture into psychological speculation. (1) Perhaps the author thought that the first example, without a comma, tended toward a "false scent": If both parties agree on who should receive the bond [that] they can lodge... oh, no, the "they" isn't working like that at all.

Comment: (2) Perhaps the fact that the first sentence is the only one in which both parts have the same subject ("they" are "both parties" while "an agreement" is not "the matter" and "a lease" is not "the following') made it feel more confusing in some way that the comma seemed to address.

Comment: Comma, comma, comma, comma consistency.  It comes and goes, it comes and go-oo-oes.

Answer (score 0):

A comma is required after all three clauses.

Perhaps: If both parties agree who should receive the bond, they can lodge a bond refund form with the relevant organisation; otherwise, the matter will be referred to a court to determine who will receive the bond.

Comment: Late in the day, but your answer is worthless without evidence or explanation. Punctuation is very flexible. I overpunctuate, compared to my wife, but the example you give is absurd. A comma after otherwise?  That separates the rider(otherwise) from its completion. Try reading it aloud to your children.